# Variable capacitive dropper power supply by means of capacitor switching with TRIAC?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, ac, triac, reactance

Is it possible to increase the reactance and thus the current of a capacitive power supply by switching an additional capacitor in parallel using a TRIAC (e.g. zero-crossing SSR)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foUoYN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The SSR/TRIAC is switching another load, so minimum trigger current should not be an issue.
Values e.g. 230VAC, 50Hz, 150nF+150nF (5mA+5mA).

Comment: I don't get it why you should use a TRIAC… do you need a variable supply? I see some problem with triggering since you have a significant current angle *especially* if you use a zero-crossing trigger. Also the trigger current has to come somewhere so I'd investigate a 'better' supply topology.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Thanks, the current angle is exactly what I am wondering about. I'm preparing to simulate it. Trigger current: see edit.

Comment: If you are going to that expense, why not a buck converter and be done with it?

Comment: @winny Yeah, it probably wouldn't be a practical solution, I'm just wondering if it could be done.

Comment: A simulation will tell.

Comment: What's wrong with the question (downvotes)?

Comment: Not me, but lack of schematic, lack of own simulation results, lack of reasoning?

Comment: It's a legitimate design question, an not a trivial one to answer too. Probably unfeasible or inconvenient, nonetheless interesting